# Add iOS on Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework

When attempting to run sudo ionic platform add ios, I am seeing an error message: Connot find module 'elementtree'

[image: (terminal screenshot)]

Answer (score 0):

Install the ionic framework first:

```
     sudo npm install -g ionic
```

and then create a test project

```
     ionic start todo test
```

and then add platform:

```
     ionic platform add ios
```

**Note**: You have to be in the test directory to add the ios platform, else you will get an error.

Comment: When i did the ionic todo test, I saw this ![error message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxn75Fl8wxdxWE5BMVZQWWVGalU/view?usp=sharing).